# Can't communicate client with Docker(Centos 7) + DNS Server(Container Ubuntu 14.04) with Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, docker, centos7

I have a problem with Docker(Centos 7) + DNS Server(Container Ubuntu 14.04) with Virtual Box. First I need explain how I built the structure:

I'm testing Docker with virtual machine, in this case with Virtual Box.

I created one virtual machine with Centos 7 with one network card in mode bridge.

Inside Centos 7 have *Docker v.1.6.0*, with interface **docker0 172.17.42.1 (Bridge)**, is a default interface for Docker. This configuration I made with **root**.

Inside Docker I created one container with Ubuntu 14.04:

```
# sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

NAT docker0 give me IP **172.17.0.2 (eth0 -> bridge)** and I intalled DNS Server with ***bind9***, this is my configuration:

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "domain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.domain.com";
};

zone "42.17.172.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.172.17.42";
};
```

**/etc/bind/db.domain.com**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     domain.com. hostmaster.domain.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.domain.com.
ns      IN      A       172.17.42.1
www     IN      A       172.17.42.1
```

**/etc/bind/db.172.17.42**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$ORIGIN 42.17.172.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     domain.com. hostmaster.domain.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.domain.com.
42      IN      PTR     ns.domain.com.
42      IN      PTR     www.domain.com.
```

Restart bind9:

```
# service bind9 restart
```

With other terminal made a commit for save the image with this configuration:

```
e.g. docker commit (ID image) (Name new image)

# docker commit 123rf dnsserver
```

Exit from the container ubuntu (poweroff container) and next run the new image:

```
# docker run -i -t -d --name=bind9 --dns=127.0.0.1 --publish=53:53/udp  --volume=/srv/docker/bind:/data --env='ROOT_PASSWORD=root' dnsserver /bin/bash
```

Now I got the DNS port (53) open in this container to the world, I think.

With another machine new, will be the client for test DNS server, with Ubuntu S.O, this machine have one network card mode bridge. I changed the DNS for 172.17.42.1 and restart the network. I tried to ping 172.17.42.1 but said this:

```
# ping 172.17.42.1
PING 172.17.42.1 (172.17.42.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 80.58.67.97 icmp_seq=21 Packet filtered
From 80.58.67.97 icmp_seq=22 Packet filtered
...
```

**¿What is *packet filtered*?** ¿Ipetables Centos7 or something, block it?

So I decided to try ping with host S.O of docker (Centos 7) and works, so I tried to test DNS and works:

```
# nslookup www.domain.com
Server:     172.17.42.1
Address:    172.17.42.1#53
```

¿Why with another client machine cannot communicate with DNS Server if the machine stay with bridge? ¿I've done wrong?

If docker0 interface is a bridge, why cant communicate to the world?

If you need more data let me know, and I will post it.

Thanks in advance.